# React Native Fetch Request Fails

Tags: react-native, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am using the react native Fetch API to get JSON data from  `https://api.github.com/users/{username}` but the request fails with the following error message.

> "TypeError: Network request failed {stack: (...), message: 'Network
>   request failed'}".

I believe for https, sometimes you get **NSURLAuthenticationChallenge**. I am not sure how to implement this. Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: it's difficult to tell without the code snippet, but you could try adding `/` to the end of the url you're using. also interpolation is done using `#{username}`

Comment: Can you provide some minimal code to reproduce this error? One way to get it is to try to `fetch` an invalid URL, but there's no way to say what caused it in your case without you showing some code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOs you may need to do the following:

You must enable your AppTransportSecurity

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

or 
[image: info.plist]

in the Info.plist.

For Android ensure that you have added permission to use INTERNET in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide an snippet of your `fetch` code?

Generally, a `fetch` statement is written like:

```
fetch(requestURL)
  .then( (response) => response.json() )
  .then( (data) => {
    this.setState({data: data});
   })
  .catch( (error) => console.log(error) )
  .done();
```

Catching the error will allow the program to proceed without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue wasn't in the code. I started emulator when had no network. After I logged in to wifi point network on emulator still wasn't functioning. I restarted emulator - all worked.

So:

1. Connect to network.
2. Restart emulator.

If it doesn't help, then check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue `React Native Fetch Request Fails` very frequently.

In my case the response from the API call was around 5kb , so i removed the unnecessary data from the API response and reduced the result size to around 1kb and all started working.

So try to limit the data you are requesting from the API.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried `XMLHttpRequest`?

As demonstrated [in the doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html), `https` is supported by `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (request.readyState !== 4) {
    return;
  }

  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log('success', request.responseText);
  } else {
    console.warn('error');
  }
};

request.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/endpoint.php');
request.send();
```

Comment: In the same doc that you posted, it shows that you can do https with Fetch as well